# Express session becomes undefined after few seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm using express-session 1.17.1 in a nodejs project.
I can store the session correctly but after some seconds, session becomes undefined.

here is the server code:

```
...
 self.app.use(session({
            secret: conf.SERVER.SECRET_WORD,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 36000000)
          }));

server = http.createServer(self.app);
...
```

here is the code to store the session when login is done:

```
...
 if(!err) {
                user.password="";
                req.session.user=user._id.toString();
                req.session.role=user.role;
                res.status(200).send(user);
              } else {
                errorHandler.processError(err, res, log);
              }
...
```

here is the code to check if session is null:

```
...
 if(req.session.user==null){
      errorHandler.processError(res.__("GENERAL.SESSION_NULL"), res, null, 401);
    }else{
// do something.
...
```

When i start the server and i make a first request all works fine and session is not null, it has the user stored. But after a few seconds if i perform the same request, session becomes undefined.
Increasing expires param doesn't modify the behavior.
Do you know what happens?

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is that express session stores the session data in memory by default. Every time when the server restarts, the sessions are gone. Have you looked into express's `.isAutheticated()` function and passport.js?

Comment: There's more to this problem than what you're' showing.  There are lots of reasons you can lose a session.  For example, if the session cookie gets lost, you won't see a reference to the session object.  If cookie persistence is turned off in the client.  If an API caller fails to include the cookie with the request, then the session will appear lost.  If the session store gets flushed.  If the session data wasn't saved properly.

Comment: Also, it does not appear there is an `expires` option for `express-session`.  The recommended option is `maxAge` and is specified like this: `app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have seen what happens. express-session doesn't support a clustered node server (I didn't know it), and my server is clustered. So I create a session doing loging in thread 1 for instace, but if another request go to thread 2, here the session is undefined.
I have changed it to use connect-mongo and store the session in mongodb.
Thanks.